# .Net Razor Pages - Create and process list of objects

Tags: c#, forms, .net-core, razor

need your thoughts on how the following can be implemented.
I need to process on the OnPost a list of <string,file> objects and do some business logic after, but at this stage, I am unsure of how to implement it either using RazorPages logic or what was usually done with MVC.

At this stage what I can't do is to get on OnPostAsync the picked values on selectedCompany and inputFile, which I was expecting to come from the formData.

Any thoughts? TY

**View**

```
(...)
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <table class="table" id="filesToProcess">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <select>
                            <option value="" name="selectedCompany">Pick a company ...</option>
                            @foreach (var company in Model.Companies)
                            {
                                <option value="@company.Id">@company.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div>
                            <input type="file" name="inputFile" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Calculate</button>
</form>
(...)
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class CalculatorModel : PageModel
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
    private ICompaniesService _companyService;
    private IIndicatorsService _indicatorsService;

    //To be presented on the front-end
    public List<CompanyDto> Companies { get; set; }

    //The initial idea would be that one row on the table of the front-end corresponds to one instance of IndicatorsRequest
    [BindProperty]
    public List<IndicatorsRequest> IndicatorsRequests { get; set; }
    public class IndicatorsRequest
    {
        public Guid CompanyGuid { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
        public List<IndicatorDto> CalculatedIndicators { get; set; }

    }

    public CalculatorModel(IHostingEnvironment environment, ICompaniesService companyService, IIndicatorsService indicatorsService)
    {
        _environment = environment;
        _companyService = companyService;
        _indicatorsService = indicatorsService;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        Companies = await this._companyService.GetCompanies();
    }

    public async Task OnPostAsync(IFormCollection formData)
    {
        try
        {
            var selectedCompanies = formData.Where(f => f.Key.Contains("selectedCompany")).ToList();
            var inputFiles = formData.Where(f => f.Key.Contains("inputFile")).ToList();
            //Do some business logic with provided companies and files;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** - https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

**View**

The '0' on *[0].CompanyGuid* and *[0].File* has obviously to be an auto-generated sequencial number.

```
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <select name="[0].CompanyGuid">  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                <option value="">Pick a company ...</option>
                                @foreach (var company in Model.Companies)
                                {
                                    <option value="@company.Id">@company.Name</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <div>
                                <input type="file" name="[0].File" /> <<<<<<<<<<<<<
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <td>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(List<IndicatorsRequest> requests)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(requests.ElementAt(0).CompanyGuid);
    }

    public class IndicatorsRequest
    {
        public Guid CompanyGuid { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).